# Base de datos .NET Core proxy inverso

Tags: base-de-datos, asp.net-core, apache2, configuración, raspberry-pi

Actualmente, por entretenimiento, estoy montando un servidor .NET Core en una raspberry pi 3 con raspbian. Hasta ahora no he tenido muchos problemas y tengo funcionando un servidor kestrel + apache con proxy inverso.

Mi problema viene cuando quiero añadir una base de datos. Me surgen dudas y por más que busco no logro encontrar nada que me ilumine. Si alguno pudiera arrojar luz a este asunto, se lo agradecería:

> - ¿Dónde debo instalar la base de datos? ¿En Kestrel? ¿En Apache?
> - En el caso de que se deban instalar en Apache, ¿hay que configurar también que se pueda acceder desde Kestrel? Supongo que sí.
> - ¿Bases de datos que soporten .NET Core?

Es algo que me llama la atención de verdad, ya que me parece muy raro que no haya encontrado nada que pueda ayudarme en la red. Quizás la cosa no está tan extendida como yo creía, o a lo mejor es que no sé buscarlo bien.En fin, muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Dónde debo instalar la base de datos? ¿En Kestrel? ¿En Apache?

En el Raspbian, Kestrel es un web server no recomendado para producción, el apache es un web server recomendado en entornos de producción, lo que juntos hacen un buen equipo al igual que kestrel + nginx.

La base de datos se instala en el servidor, en este caso el raspbian.

> En el caso de que se deban instalar en Apache, ¿hay que configurar también que se pueda acceder desde Kestrel? Supongo que sí.

El apache es un servidor web, la base de datos va en directamente en un servidor, es un servicio más, por lo cual la configuración va separada del Apache.

> ¿Bases de datos que soporten .NET Core?

Aqui la situación se pone interesante, tenemos lo siguiente:

```
ORM
--------
EF Core
Dapper
NPoco


Relational databases
--------------------
SQL Server
PostgreSQL
MySQL
SQLite
Firebird

NoSQL
------------------
Azure DocumentDB
MongoDB
RavenDB
Redis
Cassandra
CouchBase
CouchDB
Neo4j
RethinkDB
YesSql
Lucene.NET
```

Información extraída de:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/09/net-core-data-access/

si vas a utilizar Entity Framework Core, te sugiero que veas los proveedores que hay:

```
| NuGet Package                            | Supported database engines | Maintainer / Vendor         | Notes / Requirements             | Useful links |
|------------------------------------------|----------------------------|-----------------------------|----------------------------------|--------------|
| Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer  | SQL Server 2008 onwards    | EF Core Project (Microsoft) |                                  | docs         |
| Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite     | SQLite 3.7 onwards         | EF Core Project (Microsoft) |                                  | docs         |
| Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory   | EF Core in-memory database | EF Core Project (Microsoft) | For testing only                 | docs         |
| Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL    | PostgreSQL                 | Npgsql Development Team     |                                  | docs         |
| Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql         | MySQL, MariaDB             | Pomelo Foundation Project   |                                  | readme       |
| Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MyCat         | MyCAT Server               | Pomelo Foundation Project   | Pre-release, Up to EF Core 1.1   | readme       |
| EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40   | SQL Server Compact 4.0     | Erik Ejlskov Jensen         | .NET Framework                   | wiki         |
| EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact35   | SQL Server Compact 3.5     | Erik Ejlskov Jensen         | .NET Framework                   | wiki         |
| MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore           | MySQL                      | MySQL project (Oracle)      | Pre-release                      | docs         |
| FirebirdSql.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird | Firebird 2.5 and 3.x       | Jiří Činčura                | EF Core 2.0 onwards, Pre-release | blog         |
| EntityFrameworkCore.FirebirdSql          | Firebird 2.5 and 3.x       | Rafael Almeida              | EF Core 2.0 onwards              | wiki         |
| IBM.EntityFrameworkCore                  | Db2, Informix              | IBM                         | Up to EF Core 1.1, Windows       | FAQ          |
| IBM.EntityFrameworkCore-lnx              | Db2, Informix              | IBM                         | Up to EF Core 1.1, Linux         | FAQ          |
| Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore                | Oracle 9.2.0.4 onwards     | DevArt                      | Paid                             | docs         |
| Devart.Data.PostgreSql.EFCore            | PostgreSQL 8.0 onwards     | DevArt                      | Paid                             | docs         |
| Devart.Data.SQLite.EFCore                | SQLite 3 onwards           | DevArt                      | Paid                             | docs         |
| Devart.Data.MySql.EFCore                 | MySQL 5 onwards            | DevArt                      | Paid                             | docs         |
| EntityFrameworkCore.Jet                  | Microsoft Access files     | Bubi                        | EF Core 2.0, .NET Framework      | readme       |
```

Información extraída de: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/

Enlaces de utilidad:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devfish/2017/05/15/exploring-datatable-and-sqldbadapter-in-asp-net-core-2-0/

https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-mariadb-with-aspnet-core